# Lanier function in WPF xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, math, linear-algebra

I want to create a Lanier function with his Incline that I have
for example y =3.5x + 7 >>> M(incline) = 3.5, N = 7.

- don't do it by moving the points.
- Do this only with the help of an incline and not by calculating points.

I'm not very good at English so sorry if I have mistakes.
thank you in advance :)

Comment: if you want to create a Lanier function then go on and create it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.